# How to pause one thread while other is working?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is part of my code.

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Waiting for drive");
    f1.scan(d.Name);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to scan each drive. The scan function is within another windows form. When i press ok on the message box, the scan starts on C drive. But, the message box shows up again while the scan is going on. If i press ok again, D drive also gets scanned along with C. Nothing happens if i remove the MessageBox.Show(). I'm guessing the two threads are running. 
The problem is I want all the drives to be scanned in a sequential order. I tried Thread.Sleep(Timer.Infinite) to block this thread. But then the program just halts.
Help me....

```
public void scan(string path)
{
    scanPath = path;
    //scanPath = scanPathTextBox.Text;
    FileAttributes attribs = File.GetAttributes(scanPath);

    if ((attribs & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
    {
        // Perform directory scan.
        Thread scanThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var scannedFiles = new List<Tuple<string, ScanResult, string>>();

            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                scanProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
                // scanProgressBar.Value = i;
                statusLabel.Text = "Scanning...";
                logTextBox.Text = scanPath;
            }));

            _clamAV.ScanDirectory(scanPath,
                (file, result, virus) =>
                {
                    scannedFiles.Add(Tuple.Create(file, result, virus));

                    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        logTextBox.Text = file;
                    }));
                });

            // Analyse results.
            var infectedFiles = scannedFiles.Where(f => f.Item2 == ScanResult.Virus);

            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                logTextBox.Text = scanPath;
                threatInfoBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0} file(s) scanned, {1} infected\r\n",
                    scannedFiles.Count, infectedFiles.Count()));
                logTextBox.AppendText("\r\n");

                foreach (var file in infectedFiles)
                {
                    threatInfoBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0} infected with {1}\r\n", file.Item1, file.Item3));
                }

                scanProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
                scanProgressBar.Value = 100;
                statusLabel.Text = "Scan complete.";
                logTextBox.Text = " ";
                Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
                this.Hide();
                f2.ShowDialog();
            }));
        });

        scanThread.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        // Perform file scan.
        Thread scanThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            // Signal start of scan on UI thread.
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                scanProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;

                statusLabel.Text = "Scanning...";
                //scanProgressBar.Value = i;
            }));

            string virusName = "";

            ScanResult scanResult = _clamAV.ScanFile(scanPath, ScanOptions.StandardOptions, out virusName);

            // Report scan completion.
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                statusLabel.Text = "Scan complete.";
                logTextBox.Text = " ";
                scanProgressBar.Value = 100;

                logTextBox.Text = scanPath;
                if (scanResult == ScanResult.Clean)
                    threatInfoBox.AppendText("File is clean.\r\n");
                else
                    threatInfoBox.AppendText("File is infected with " + virusName + ".\r\n");
                logTextBox.AppendText("\r\n");
            }));
        });

        // Begin scanning.
        scanThread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything related with threads in your code. How about posing a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: As @Eser said, there is nothing to do with threads here. The second message box is showing because the scan of C: finished. Either it's faster than you think, or `scan` is broken. Either way, this is not related to threads, so I'm removing the tags.

Comment: This code is part of a winform while scan() is within another form(which has a thread), Since the scanning and messagebox are being shown at the same time, i'm thinking the threads are running.

Comment: can include scan() method, or its signature ?

Comment: @sanjay what don't you show the code for `scan` , so that we can see the source of problem.

Comment: the signature is 
scan(string )

Comment: the code wont fit in the comment field

Comment: @sanjay of course. you should post it in question.

Comment: @sanjay good that you have posted the code. But why don't you post a compilable code.  Please remove all those `>` s

Comment: this has a lot of external references. So i wouldn't call it compilable.

Comment: @sanjay at least easier to read now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and lock your scan function. Aparently it is not thread safe.
Try something like:

```
class TestScan {

 private static Object oMutex = new Object();

 public void scan(){
   lock(oMutex){
     /* do work */
   }
 } // end of scan method.

 /***/

 }
```

Every thread that falls into this method will wait on the lock call if there is another thread already executing it. It is basically just a simple mutex.
You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx).

Comment: This should not be an answer, but a comment instead.

Comment: I know that but I can only comment if I have 50 reputation. If I keep getting  down votes for trying to help I will never get there..

Comment: @RicardoRacciore If you keep getting downvotes, don't you think you should try another approach? The limit is to reduce the amount of spam in the system. Post answers that you're sure about for now. 50 rep doesn't take long to achieve.

Comment: It was not me downvoting, but only because I don't want to deter you from progressing. You should wait to reach the required rep before commenting and all will be ok. Rules are there for a reason, you know.

Comment: @sanjay Then make a small reproducible snippet that you can post here.

Comment: Sorry for that then. @sanjay I've posted something that might help you.

Comment: I'm calling scan() from Form3. scan() is in Form1. While scan() is getting executed, the for each() loop within Form3 is also being executed. This is why i think two threads are running.

Comment: Have to tryed to lock it? Go to Form1 class and declare a new variable (just like the oMutex I´ve shown you). At the begining of the scan method do the lock(oMutex). Lock will work just like a "traffic stop". If a thread is scanning the other needs to wait until the thread is done to move forward.

Comment: @RicardoRacciore Your code wouldn't work since the caller of `scan` is the same thread so `lock(oMutex)` would never block. You should move it to somewhere inside the thread method.